# Add a global leave event

Tags: c#, events, controls

I have a Form with many controls. Some controls have `Leave` events and I would like to add a global handler to *all* controlls.

What I want to do:

- if a control have a leave event: First fire that event and then execute the global-handler
- if a control does not have a leave event only execute the global handler.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think this is clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add a generic handler and wire it to the `Leave` event of every control on the form:

```
private Constructor()
{
    foreach (Control Item in this.Controls)
        Item.Leave += Item_Leave;
}

private void Item_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("do something");
}
```

This would fire for every single control on the form.

The `Leave` event on each control would also be executed.

Comment: `This would fire for every single control on the form.`  Unless those controls are in a panel.

Comment: I'm not sure I can see where the OP mentioned having a `Panel` (or other container controls).  However, that can easily be solved by recursively adding the Leave event to nested controls, it's no biggie

Comment: Yes, all the controls ara in a Tabpage, naturally